# gulp-less is not compiling a css file

Tags: npm, less, gulp

I'm new to using Gulp and am trying to compile `base.less` into a `main.css` file. I plan on adding additional less files to be compiled. So far the js compiles nicely when running `gulp`, but not the less.

My `gulpfile.js` looks like this:

```
// Include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');

 // Include plugins
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

 // Concatenate JS Files
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('static/js/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
});

 // LESS
var less = require('gulp-less');
var path = require('path');

gulp.task('less', function () {
  return gulp.src('static/less/*.less')
    .pipe(less({
      paths: [ path.join(__dirname, 'less', 'includes') ]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'));
});

 // Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['scripts']);
```

The `package.json` like this:

```
{
  "name": "website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-less": "^3.0.3",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.4.2",
  }
}
```

File structure:

```
|-- build
    |-- js
        |-- main.js
        |-- main.min.js
|-- gulpfile.js
|-- index.html
|-- node_modules
    |-- all of those...
|-- package.json
|-- static
    |-- img
    |-- js
        |-- base.js
    |-- less
        |-- base.less
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your gulpfile.js file, notably, line `gulp.task('default', ['scripts']);`, it doesn't appear that you're calling the task to compile the less files.

Perhaps you meant to use:

```
gulp.task('default', ['scripts','less']);
```

Comment: Thank you! Tripped at the finish line.

Comment: Welcome. Happens to the best of us.